# Django , how to extend from template in main static folder

Tags: python, django

I have folder called mytemplates for sites base templates

`Project ----App1,App2,App3,static`

Now in my static folder i have folder called `mytemplates/temp1/index.html`

Now in my app1

`app1/templates/app1/index.html`

I want to do this

```
{% extends "/static/mytemplates/temp1/index.html" %}
```

But its saying that template not found

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write `/static`.

You must have your `/static` folder defined in [`settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs) otherwise django's template loader will never search there. You must write out the full path, not the relative path.

By default, template loaders search inside of the template folder, so they don't depend on which template folder they are in. Meaning, writing `{% extends "mytemplates/temp1/index.html" %}` will result in django making a list of all your template dirs, appending `mytemplates/temp1/index.html` to the absolute path of each, and determining whether or not the concatenated path exists. If it doesn't, it keeps trying your other template directories. If after trying all your directories no match is found, django raises an exception.

Writing simply `{% extends "mytemplates/temp1/index.html" %}` will work assuming your `static` folder is in your `settings.TEMPLATES_DIR` tuple and that `"mytemplates/temp1/index.html"` exists in `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put a full pathname to the file in, look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) for the exact syntax. If's the same name that you would call your template from your view.